# Find yourself somewhere (e.g. mass demonstration)

Tags: phrase-usage

According to the Macmillan Dictionary, [**find yourself somewhere**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/find-yourself-somewhere) means to realize that you are in a place or doing something **without really intending or planning to**.

In this regard, I wonder whether this phrase can be used to express a situation you got into by chance.

> Once I went out to buy milk. Eventually, I found myself at a mass demonstration. I didn't want to protest against closure of the pit and couldn’t realize how I got there.

EDIT.
The  reason for being involved in the demonstration is that one was curious about what was going on, and got too close to the rally. Then one found oneself at the epicentre of events, suddenly and unexpectedly.

Comment: *Eventually* is probably not the best word here, but your use of the phrase *I found myself* is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *eventually* makes this seem like you had a memory lapse and ended up somewhere other than what you intended. Maybe you started wandering around? Because in this example we have no idea what happened in the mean time.

Maybe better would be:

> Once I went out to buy milk. **On the way there**, I found myself at a mass demonstration. I didn't want to protest against closure of the pit and couldn’t realize how I got there.

Clearly it was not the plan since you said you were going to the store.

Here is an example using *eventually* where you know basically what was happening:

> I kept driving on the road along the Russian River, and **eventually** we arrived at the beach.

Comment: By _eventually_ I meant something like _to cut to the chase_ or _to put it briefly_, but definitely not a memory lapse :) The situation is that you were curious about what was going on, and kept going closer. Everyone shouted, someone called the police. And suddenly you found yourself at the epicentre of events.  That's as it may be.

Comment: Then I might go with something like *as it turned out* or *as events unfolded*. But to really pin down this phrasing, we need more context in the question (your comment is better).

Comment: I see, the _eventually_ is a wrong choice here. I find that helpful.